# Reg exp to parse variable from URL

Tags: regex, jmeter

I have an URL in JMeter script response, with template like this:

1. simplified case:

"https://HOST/something/**028405dc6dl015c17bb5dbf419ab471d2**"

2. real case, with symbol "-" in URL:

"https://HOST-host/something1-something2/**028405dc6dl015c17bb5dbf419ab471d2**"

I need to parse from this URL template only **value in bold**.

I tried `([^\/]+?)"` - it returns value with ",

`([^\/]+?)$"` - it doesn't work.

What is the best way to get only value **028405dc6dl015c17bb5dbf419ab471d2** using regular expressions in JMeter?

Thank you for solution with 1st case on regex site, it looks very nice. Unfortunatelly, I missed that "-" could change the regexp.
What are the options if "-" is in URL (2 case)?

Comment: `[0-9a-z]+$` would extract everything after the final slash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `something` doesn't change you can go for "something" like:

```
/something/(\w+)"
```

[image]

where:

- `w` matches any "word" character (alphanumeric, case-insensitive, including underscores)
- `+` is for repetition

See [Meta Characters](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html#meta_chars) chapter of JMeter user manual for regular expressions for more details.

If you have troubles with coming up with a proper regular expression you can consider switching to the [Boundary Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Boundary_Extractor), all you need to do is to provide "left" and "right" boundaries and it will fetch everything in-between:

[image]

More information: [The Boundary Extractor vs. the Regular Expression Extractor in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-boundary-extractor-vs-the-regular-expression-extractor-in-jmeter)

Comment: @Dmitry T, thank you for simplifying solution!

Answer (score 3):

With your shown samples, please try following regex. This will create 1 capturing group which will have value you need to fetch. Simple explanation would be checking if value starts from http keeping s as optional(for https), matching : 2 slashes till last slash, finally keeping all values after it in 1st capturing group.

```
^"https?:\/\/.*\/(.*)"$
```

[Online demo for above regex](https://regex101.com/r/qu23xn/1)

Comment: quotes are part of the string but shouldn't be matched, if I understand correctly.

Comment: @PoulBak, oh sure, I thought its not part of it, I have changed regex now, thank you.

Comment: Yes, correct. Quotes are part of the string and I need only value between right slash / 
 and right qute symbol ".

Comment: @NadezhdaT, sure, code has been edited accordingly, thank you.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13, Thank you for update. It works and looks nice, but I missed that - in HOST and something could change the picture. Could you please help, how should regexp be transformed, if both HOST and something contain - , like "https://HOST-host/something1-something2/028405dc6dl015c17bb5dbf419ab471d2".

Comment: @NadezhdaT, sure, I could help you. Could you please provide more clear samples like: `http://localhost:80/test2/test2/catch-this_string` once they will make things clear here, thank yiu

Comment: @NadezhdaT, Yes, this should work for that URL also, please do check Online link https://regex101.com/r/U0eNNA/1 once and let me know if this helps you.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13, I added as case2 in topic. Thank you for your time, the problem is in tool specifics, JMeter needs some magic additional regexp transformations (over offered which work fine on regex site, but not always in JMeter with the same syntax). Additionally in this case "-" add unexpected behavior of regexp in JMeter and I still have no solution for this tool with regexp transformation. Thank you for your nice regexps!

Comment: @NadezhdaT, oh ok sure, thanks for letting know.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
^"https?:\/\/[^\/]*\/([^\/]*)"$
```